# How to do skip and take functions in javascript for Json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to do that in javascript:

```
     for (int i = 0; i <= pieces; i++)
      {
       List<product> piecesProuducts = productList.Skip(i * 2).Take(2).ToList();
      }
```

I have a json array. I want to get two records block from this json array as above linq code in javascript. Is that possible and how?

Comment: What does the JSON look like and what should the end result look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A JSON array is just a JavaScript array, so you can use [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Here's an example:

```
var productList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
var piecesProuducts = []

for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    piecesProuducts.push(productList.slice(i*2, i*2+2));
}

console.log(piecesProuducts)
```