# Show 10 jquery objects at a time

Tags: jquery, html, object, show-hide

I have a website that will hold 100s of objects that have like the following:

```
 function Products (type, title, description, cost, image){
 this.type = type;
 this.title = title;
 this.description = description;
 this.cost = cost;
 this.image = image;
 this.displayInfo = function(){
  var info ="<div class='p-image'>";
      info += this.image + "</div><div class='p-title'>";
      info += this.title + "</div><div class='p-cost'>";
      info += "Online Product Cost: $" + this.cost + "</div><div class='p-desc'>";
      info += "<strong>DESCRIPTION:</strong> " + this.description + "</div>";

     return info;
 }
 }


 // define an array to store products
 var product_list = [];

 var im = "<img src='http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/911wQX4ahaL._SL1500_.jpg' id = 'image'>";
 var desc = "<br><span style = 'font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;'>Developer: </span>Teyon<br> <span style = 'font-weight: bold;'>Platforms: </span>PS3, WIN, X360<br> <span style = 'font-weight: bold;'>Release Date: </span>2013</br><span id = 'para'> Sequel to Heavy Fire: Afghanistan, in which soldiers are sent after a captured spy who holds the plans to a secret Iranian nuclear weapons facility.</span>";
 var product = new Products('v fps win xbone ps3','Heavy Fire: Shattered Spear',desc, 10.00, im);
product_list.push(product);

var im = "<img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/c5/AliensColonialMarinesBox.png' id = 'image'>";
var desc = "<br><span style = 'font-weight: bold;'>Developer: </span>Gearbox Software<br> <span style = 'font-weight: bold;'>Platforms: </span>PS3, WIN, X360<br> <span style = 'font-weight: bold;'>Release Date: </span>2013</br><span id = 'para'>True sequel to James Cameron's film, the story of Aliens: Colonial Marines takes place nearly 17 weeks after the events of Alien 3 and almost 199 years prior to the events of Alien Resurrection, as the cryotubes containing Ellen Ripley, Corporal Hicks, Newt, and the android Bishop had ejected from the Sulaco. </span>";
product_list.push(new Products('v fps','Aliens: Colonial Marines',desc, 10.00, im));  

displayProducts();

function displayProducts() {

    for (var i=0; i<product_list.length; i++){
    //product_list[i].type can determine which are chosen
        var divrow = "<div class='list "+ product_list[i].type + "' data-index='" +i+ "' >";
        divrow +=  product_list[i].displayInfo() + "</div>"
    $('#main-list').append(divrow);
    //tried append to '#list' and '.list' but didn't work either so made main-list div
    }
 }
```

........

When they display, once the page loads, is all of them at once. So the "height" of my page is enormous. I want the list to drop down from 100s to just 10 showing at a time. Similar to how google shows their website:

[image]

I have never made this .show() version before so I was wondering how to do this. I just want them to dynamically update on the page because I have a shopping cart table on the same page as well. Any ideas or suggestions?

My website so far looks like this:

[image]

Comment: A quick search yields [this paging plugin](https://plugins.jquery.com/paging/).  There's a simpler one [here](http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/).

Comment: I am looking to program my own. I thought to do this you just need a .show() hide function ?

Comment: i see your second link. I will check it out

Comment: You would need something more akin to Skip and Take in Linq, if you wanted to roll your own.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622850/how-to-do-skip-and-take-functions-in-javascript-for-json-array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [**a functioning sample**](http://jsfiddle.net/s8vez65L/1/) to get you started. Here is the relevent code from it:

HTML:

```
<div id="main-list"></div>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
//set a variable to track the number of pages
var pageCount = 0;

function displayProducts() {
    //create a container 'page'
    var page = $('<div class="page"/>');

    //parse your data array
    for (var i = 0; i < product_list.length; i++) {
        //create the item div
        var divrow = "<div class='list " + product_list[i].type + "' data-index='" + i + "' >";
        divrow += product_list[i].displayInfo + "</div>"
        //append it to the 'page
        page.append(divrow);

        //if we reach 10 items (or the end of the list), add the 'page' to the doc, and reset the page variable
        if ((i + 1) % 10 == 0 || i == product_list.length-1) {
            //add page
            $('#main-list').append(page);
            //increase page count
            pageCount++;
            //reset the page variable to a new blank 'page' div
            page = $('<div class="page hidden"/>');
        }
    }

    //simple pager anchor elements
    for (var j = 0; j < pageCount; j++) {
        //using data-page attribute to refer to the 0 based index
        $('#pager').append('<a href="#" data-page="' + j + '">' + (j + 1) + '</a>&nbsp;');
    }
}
//hide all pages then show the one that equals the 'data-page' index
$('#pager').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    $('.page').addClass('hidden').eq($(this).attr('data-page')).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

HTH
-Ted